# Connection created but not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, cordova, firebird

I am developping a Cordova application using a Node JS server and firebird databases.
The two databases exist and I can connect on it via isql-fb.

When I create a first connection via a phone, the connexion works, as well as the queries done on this connection.

However, when I create a second connection, it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

Connection table, which regroups the connections as ["username", connexion] tables

```
var connectionTable = [];
```

Function that connects to databases and adds the connections in connectionTable :

```
function connectionToDB(username, password, dbAddress){
    var con = fb.createConnection(); 
    con.connectSync(dbAddress, username, password, '');

    var newConnection = [username, con];
    connectionTable.push(newConnection);

    console.log('connection finished'); //it is displayed for both connections so I think it works  
};
```

Function that returns the wanted connection via the username entered :

```
function getConnection(username){
    for(x in connectionTable){
        if(connectionTable[x][0]==username) {
            return connectionTable[x][1];
        }
        else {console.log("No connection found with username : " + username); return 0;}
}
```

};

And then, on my node JS server, I have this "route" :

```
app.get('/checkAccount/:username', function(req, res){
    console.log("checkAccount avant body");
    console.log(req.params);    
    var usernameAsking = req.params.username;   

    console.log("usernameAsking = " + usernameAsking); //returns username in both cases

    var connexionLinked = getConnection(usernameAsking);
    console.log(typeof connexionLinked);
    console.log(connexionLinked);
    if(connexionLinked == 0) console.log("Problem. No linked connexion found");
    else console.log("connexion found");

    var query = connexionLinked.querySync("SELECT * from shops");
    var rows = query.fetchSync('all', true);
    console.log(sys.inspect(rows)); 
    var shopNameString = JSON.stringify(rows);
    console.log("string : " + shopNameString);  
    res.send(shopNameString);
});
```

So for the first connection done to a database, it works very well, and does return me the values of its database.

However, it does not for the second different connection and it says it is equal to 0, so I assume it did not find it in GetConnection.

I do not understand why it works for one and not another... I also tried to connect to several different connections earlier, not with this process and it works. So the problem is not that we can't have several connection on the same NodeJS server, but that in this context, we cannot find the good one apparently...

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

**-- EDIT --**

The connections worked this way. The error was in the for loop of getConnection(username). I let this post here though if anyone tries to do a table of connections.

Thank you all.

Comment: so your `usernameAsking ` is right (exists in the array) and your 2 logs show `number` and `0`?

Comment: Yes, here is what the console shows :  in both cases :

Comment: first : checkAccount avant body
{ username: 'BARBARA' }
usernameAsking = BARBARA
object
Connection { inAsyncCall: false, inTransaction: false, connected: true }
connexion found
[ { /*correct data is displayed*/} ]
string : [{/*correct data also*/}]
checkAccount ended

Comment: second : 
{ username: 'FASTMAG' }
usernameAsking = FASTMAG
No connection found with username : FASTMAG
number
0
Problem. No linked connexion found
TypeError: connexionLinked.querySync is not a function

Comment: (sorry for the pity presentation in the comments)

Comment: how your connectionToDB is used?, btw why are you using in sync manner, and not async?

Comment: In an app route, we define the username, database address and password of the database when someone logs in. Then we create a connection variable with : var connection = fb.createConnection();  connection.connectSync(dbAddress, username, password, ''); . Then, we add it as [username, connection] in tableConnection.

Comment: The sync manner is because I'm using the firebird module for Javascript ( here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebird ). In the example, they use querySync so I did it this way and it worked so I kept working with it :)

Comment: I'll suggest to turn to the non-blocking way, it is possible that during creation 2nd connection your node process is blocked, and no connection was created, check if your second connection is actually created.

Comment: I think you're right, I was checking what were the values of the connections. Turns out, for the second connection created, the value  is the same as the first one. I'll try to do something with the non-blocking way you suggested, thank you :)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding pertinent details in comments. And also please show the connection string you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I feel stupid. But now we know the creation of connections works this way.
Here is the most ankward error no one could ever do :

```
function getConnection(username){
    for(x in connectionTable){
        console.log("connectionTable : " + connectionTable[x]); 
        console.log("connectionTable FULL: " + connectionTable); 
        console.log("connectionTable[x][0] : " + connectionTable[x][0]); 
        console.log(connectionTable.length);
        if(connectionTable[x][0]==username) {

            return connectionTable[x][1];
        }

    }
    console.log("No connection found with username : " + username);     
    return 0; // Error solved : The return was not supposed to be in the for loop
              //it was only checking the first username value. 

};
```

Thank you all for your time and help :)